# ImageMagick isn't displaying arabic characters correctly

Tags: imagemagick, imagemagick-convert

So I am trying to display an Arabic word using ImageMagick.

This is my code:

```
convert -size 1144x800 -background transparent -font "arabic_reg.ttf" -encoding Unicode label:@arabic.utf8 "oops.png"
```

@arabic.utf8 is saved in utf-8 and arabic_reg.ttf is an arabic font.

This is the result

[letters are detached and inverted](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y5M8C.png)

adding -direction right-to-left doesn't seem to help also.

I am running ImageMagick 6.9.6-2 on mac.

> Version: ImageMagick 6.9.6-2 Q16 x86_64 2016-10-20
> Copyright: Copyright (C) 1999-2016 ImageMagick Studio LLC
> Features: Cipher DPC Modules
> Delegates (built-in): bzlib djvu fftw fontconfig freetype gslib jbig jng jp2 jpeg lcms ltdl lzma openexr png ps tiff webp x xml zlib

Any idea how to fix this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Ran into the same problem, you gotta use pango and install the fonts in your system :)